# What is the most efficient way to install all libraries, such as libgpg-error, libffi, libgcrypt for windows 10?

Tags: windows, libraries

I have been trying to install all these libraries for the QEMU build but they seem to throw various errors one after the other. I am spending so much time installing these libraries and solving the errors. Is there any easy way where I can get the whole package installed? or a guide on how to install?

**Update:** I was working with MingW and understood I could install few libraries from their installers or with command ming-get. But Libgcrypt  is still not installed